# PHP shell_exec() - having problems running command

Tags: php, exec

Im new to php shell commands so please bear with me. I am trying to run the shell_exec() command on my server. I am trying the below php code:

```
$output = shell_exec('tesseract picture.tif text_file -l eng');
echo "done";
```

I have the picture.tif in the same directory as the php file. In my shell I can run this without a problem.

It takes a while to run the code, then it doesnt make the text_file like it does when I run it in command prompt.

Comment: How long does the command take to run on the command line?

Comment: Try using the absolute path to `tesseract`.  To find it out, run `which tesseract` from the command line.  Then take that result and use that path in the `shell_exec` call...

Comment: @Orbling - I think about 10 seconds.

Comment: @bryan sammon: It takes longer than that to execute the PHP script? [Alter to the absolute path as recommended by ircmaxell first]

Comment: I just altered the path and it takes the same amount of time and still doesnt write the text_file. You think it may be leaving it in a different directory?

Comment: The thing I am trying to do is just loop through a directory on my computer. I dont know of a better way to do it than php. I have a linux system w/ shell. Should I write a loop in shell instead? I just need a text file to generate with the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment:

> Should I write a loop in shell
>   instead?

You can write a very simple shell script to run the command in a loop.  Create the script file first:

```
touch myscript.sh
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod 700 myscript.sh
```

Then open it with a text editor such as `vim` and add this:

```
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 5;  i++  ))
do
  tesseract picture.tif text_file -l eng
done
```

Thats the very basics of it (not sure what else you need), but that syntax should help get you started.  To run the script, do this if you're in the same directory as the script:

```
./myscript.sh
```

Or specify the full path to run it from anywhere:

```
/path/to/mydir/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Just got back to see someone answered. This was def the simplest way to do this. I had already started on this before you answered and its going to be by far the best solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a permissions issue? My guess is that PHP isn't running with the same permissions that you do when you execute the command directly from the command prompt. What OS are you running on?